# How best to return async tasks to the caller

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm inserting rows in to Cassandra, although my question is about Cassandra but how best to use an async API in general.  In a nutshell, I generate an id for a row in C# code and do the insert asynchronously and want to return the id to the caller.  The sample code below shows what I've tried so far, all of which work, but which is best?  Are there alternatives or better solutions?

Say I have some class and all the Cassandra gubbins set up.  This could equally be a file I'm serializing the class to; this isn't a Cassandra question.

```
class MyClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

ISession cassandraSession;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
```

My first attempt was to use `async+await`

```
async Task<Guid> Insert(MyClass someObject)
{
    someObject.Id = TimeUuid.NewId();

    BoundStatement insert = preparedStatement.Bind(someObject.Id, someObject.Text);

    await cassandraSession.ExecuteAsync(insert);

    return someObject.Id;
}
```

After some research, my understanding as this is sub-optimal because it will block on the `await` and create a whole new state machine etc.

Next I tried this:

```
Task<Guid> Insert(MyClass someObject)
{
    someObject.Id = TimeUuid.NewId();

    BoundStatement insert = preparedStatement.Bind(someObject.Id, someObject.Text);

    cassandraSession.ExecuteAsync(insert);

    return Task.FromResult(someObject.Id);
}
```

Seems okay, no blocking, but could the caller receive the id and query before the insert has completed and not find the row?  I tried a continuation:

```
Task<Guid> Insert(MyClass someObject)
{
    someObject.Id = TimeUuid.NewId();

    BoundStatement insert = preparedStatement.Bind(someObject.Id, someObject.Text);

    return cassandraSession
        .ExecuteAsync(insert)
        .ContinueWith(t => someObject.Id);
}
```

That also seems to work and means the task the caller awaits would include the insert, so should ensure the insert will have completed.

Have I missed or misunderstood anything?

Comment: You say "my understanding as this is sub-optimal because it will block on the await". This is not true. Did you actually test this to see if it blocks?

Comment: How do you consume the `Insert` method? Is the caller of the `Insert` method asynchronous?

Comment: Your middle one definitely looks broken - `ExecuteAsync` returns something that's awaitable and yet you're ignoring it.

Comment: @YacoubMassad I thought it would block based on my (mis)reading of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx - "_The await operator tells the compiler that the async method can't continue past that point until the awaited asynchronous process is complete. **In the meantime, control returns to the caller of the async method.** The suspension of an async method at an await expression doesn't constitute an exit from the method, and finally blocks don’t run._"  Re-reading it I'm paying more attention to the bolded sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` doesn't block so your statement is technically inaccurate. But I believe what you mean is "it does not continue execution" which is correct.

> create a whole new state machine

Yes it does, but it is quite cheap. The `await+async` here is responsible for 4 small object allocations if I count correctly. That is not that significant. In particular it disappears in the noise due to the highly expensive database call.

Your attempt 2 has no chance of working as you recognized.

Attempt 3 works, but the code is of worse quality. Prefer 1.

Comment: Thanks.  Out of interest, what's the difference between 1 and 3.  Why is 3 worse?

Comment: 1 is natural code. 3 is more complicated. Becomes worse the more your code does.